# How to load a Picasa image from URI?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, picasa, android-contentresolver

I'm using `ACTION_PICK` intent to select an image from gallery. Some albums like *"Posts"*, *"Profile Photos"*, etc are marked with Picasa icon. For images from such albums I get a URI similar to this:

```
content://com.google.android.gallery3d.provider/picasa/item/5769844615871490082
```

I can load an image from this URI using `ContentResolver` and `BitmapFactory` with no problem:

```
final InputStream ist = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(intent.getData());
final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ist);
```

But I'm unable to load an image using stored URI after I restart the application. I'm getting this when `decodeStream()` is called:

```
03-11 12:34:56.502: A/libc(1172): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000408 (code=1), thread 1462 03-11 12:34:56.502:
    W/ActivityManager(478): Permission Denial: opening provider
    com.android.gallery3d.provider.GalleryProvider from
    ProcessRecord{41cdd220 1172:com.mycompany.myapp/u0a10085}
    (pid=1172, uid=10085) requires
    com.google.android.gallery3d.permission.GALLERY_PROVIDER or
    com.google.android.gallery3d.permission.GALLERY_PROVIDER
```

I tried to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gallery3d.permission.GALLERY_PROVIDER"/>
```

to the manifest file but it didn't help.

I think my problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558177/security-exception-when-trying-to-access-a-picasa-image-on-device-running-4-2), but no solution is given there, only a workaround. Is it possible to request a permission to access a stored URI?

Comment: The content-URIs are most likely time-limited, and only work in the context of the ACTION_PICK. You'll need to cache the image in your app, as there's no guarantee that the content is even available later on.

Comment: i swear im gona run into the same problem, favorite again

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: I open image data as a stream and save it into a local file. See suggested solution below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try opening input stream like this

```
ContentResolver res = context.getContentResolver();
Uri uri = Uri.parse(intent.getData().toString());
res.openInputStream(uri);
```