# Google maps marker – out of heap memory exception occurs

Tags: android, xamarin, maps, markers

Google maps marker – out of heap memory exception occurs when the number of markers increase in google map. I am generating the markers in runtime, each marker is a type of bitmap images and its size is 128 kB.

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16887448/4385913)

Comment: can you post some code to show how your adding these markers to google maps.