# Picking an image from Android Gallery & Picassa

Tags: android, image, android-gallery, picasa

I am trying to open an image/picture in the Gallery built-in app from inside my application as described in [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/get-pick-an-image-from-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically/)

My "picker" activity works fine as long as the image is stored in the device, but the gallery app also displays images from Picassa, which returns a null path.

Does anyone knows how to fix this, either by getting the path or tell the "picker" intent to ignore Picassa as a provider, and only show me what is on my device?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558177/security-exception-when-trying-to-access-a-picasa-image-on-device-running-4-2/13725266#13725266)

What I did was just check the returning Uri to see if the selected image was a picassa image. probably not the best option but it works since there is no way to tell the image picker what images to show